# Array from text file return lots of empty space using php

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I'm trying to extract data from a text file that generated from a .asp website that will be load into interface.txt file. Format of the data are below *(All the name in the text has been masked)*:

[format of data in text file split by comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbaIa.png)

```
801B,SAMPING,VAC,25999,2,R**NA** B**T* A** R*H**  ,FEMALE,2017-05-29, ,14:58:01.8000000
820A,SAMPING,VAC,11191,5,M**A*M** H*I**L B** K*M**R*LBA**R*N  ,MALE,2017-05-31, ,20:33:19.0300000
505,SELENDANG,OCC,26194,2,I*F** *MR** B** M**D H**A* *AK*R**D**  ,MALE,2017-06-01, ,17:49:54.6530000
810,SAMPING,VAC,14251,6,P**I** B**T* S*L**H  ,FEMALE,2017-05-29, ,00:10:47.8630000
602B,SUTERA,OCC,26172,2,G**R*E C**E K** Z**  ,MALE,2017-06-01, ,15:22:18.9970000
```

By using below codes, I'm trying to extract the data:

```
$file       = "C:/btemp/bed-interface.txt";
$fileToLoad = fopen($file, "rb");
while(!feof($fileToLoad)){
    $data       = fgets($fileToLoad);
    $extract    = array_map('trim', explode(',', $data));
    $bnum       = trim(preg_replace('[^\s]', '', $extract[0]));
    //other array continue here
}
fclose($fileToLoad);
```

Above codes will split the string by using comma but then when I'm trying to check each array **strlen** return, it will shows the incorrect value. For example, the first row data when return the **$bnum** it will show **strlen** of **7** instead **4**. This will continue to other data. Can refer to below image to see the result of each return character. Each length are is in bracket. *(All the name in the text has been masked)*

```
801B (7)    SAMPING (13)    O   25999 (9)   2 (1)   R**NA** B**T* A** R*H** (45)                F   2017-05-29 (19) 14:58:01 (15)
820A (7)    SAMPING (13)    O   11191 (9)   5 (1)   M**A*M** H*I**L B** K*M**R*LBA**R*N (69)    F   2017-05-31 (19) 20:33:19 (15)
505 (5)     SELENDANG (17)  O   26194 (9)   2 (1)   I*F** *MR** B** M**D H**A* *AK*R**D** (73)  F   2017-06-01 (19) 17:49:54 (15)
810 (5)     SAMPING (13)    O   14251 (9)   6 (1)   P**I** B**T* S*L**H (37)                    F   2017-05-29 (19) 00:10:47 (15)
602B (7)    SUTERA (11)     O   26172 (9)   2 (1)   G**R*E C**E K** Z** (37)                    F   2017-06-01 (19) 15:22:18 (15)
```

[Result of explode and length of each array return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72DNr.png)

So, how to prevent this to happen. How to remove all the space. Already tried using *trim, array_map, preg_replace* still space appear when count using **strlen**. Even to do match in mysql query, it will return **false** cause *the space has made the query return false*.

Comment: Try `unpack('C*', $string)` to see what exact bytes the string contains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the value that has been sent to the database, seems that all the character in the database has unknown character after every each value.

For example **SAMPING = S□A□M□P□I□N□G□** *(there will be □ as unknown char and will read by **strlen** as **14 character**)*

By using correct **preg_replace** for each array retrieve:

```
$bnum       = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_ -]/','',$extract[0]);
```

instead of this:

```
$bnum       = trim(preg_replace('[^\s]', '', $extract[0]));
```

it will remove all unwanted unknown character in the array and will save the correct value to the database.

Comment: The strings are probably a UTF-16 or something like that, where each character is encoded as at least 2 bytes.

Comment: Yes, probably the string are UTF-16. The data are coming from 3rd party software and cannot be modified.  So, at my side what I can do is by remove all the unwanted character using correct regex preg_replace before stored in the database.